# Is it viable to use a smart contract for string based authentication?

Tags: solidity, security

I am aware that security on the network is done at the private key level, but would love to know the security implications of having an additional password/string and time-based level of security on a smart contract.

A simple implementation of that would be something like this:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.21;

contract PasswordTimeLock {
    uint timelock;
    bytes32 hashlock;
    address owner;
    string data = "hello world";

    function PasswordTimeLock(string _password) public {
        owner = msg.sender;
        hashlock = keccak256(owner, _password);
    }

    function unlock(string _password) public returns (bool) {
        require(keccak256(owner, _password) == hashlock);
        timelock = now + 20 seconds;
        return true;
    }

    function read() public view returns (string) {
        require(now < timelock);
        return data;
    }
}
```

Is there any exposure to the actual string passed to the `unlock` function or the constructor?

Comment: It's a public blockchain. Anyone can read the string you passed in the constructor.

Comment: @smarx Figured as much. How would one get to the string passed in the constructor?

Answer (score 1):

As smarx says in his comment, anyone can read the password passed in the constructor. To answer your question directly, yes, the string passed to `unlock` is also exposed. Additionally, `data` can be read by anybody directly from the blockchain.